# Peter's GDB Tutorial

Tags: gdb, mirror

About two months ago, I found this incredibly great [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) tutorial written by Peter Jay Salzman.

It used to be accessible [here](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/), but I think the site has gone down for a couple of months now.

I found it on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140831121704/http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/02a-Memory_Layout_And_The_Stack.php#stackframesandthestack), and wanted to mirror it. I tried [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) and [HTTrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTrack) to no avail; they both errored out. Googling didn't reveal much either.

Is there a mirror of this site?

Comment: Is this it? - http://www.flipkart.com/art-debugging-gdb-ddd-eclipse/1593271743-7sx3f7re8b

Comment: @ Krakkos - Not quite.  His online tutorial has similar content.  But it was free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Peter's GDB tutorial](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/) is now available on [Peter Jay Salzman's website](http://dirac.org/).  Not sure why it was down when this question was posed in December '09.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not Peter Jay Salzman.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a modestly updated version of Peter's excellent tutorial, *Using The GNU GDB Debugger* [here](http://www3.sympatico.ca/rsquared/gdb/).  It is based on the latest archive of his site, from archive.org, but it is considerably more reliable (the internet archive often seems to not want to load pages).

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

- [http://eric.bachard.free.fr/UTBM_LO22/P07/C/Documentation/C/tutorial_gdb/Peter's_gdb_Tutorial.html](http://eric.bachard.free.fr/UTBM_LO22/P07/C/Documentation/C/tutorial_gdb/Peter%27s_gdb_Tutorial.html)

  CAUTION: above mirror not complete. The mirror seems to be quite old as chapter 6,7,8 seem to be missing.
- Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20080511001311/http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/

You may also be interested in reading this article:
[Mastering Linux debugging techniques](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debug/) ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debug/ )

Answer (score 0):

`wget` worked fine for me.

```
wget --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/20121223 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8' http://web.archive.org/web/20080511001311/http%3A//www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/
```

Comment: I want the entire tree, not just the index page.

Comment: @sheepsimulator, my bad.  Not everything is on archive.org and I don't know where else to get it.  Sorry.

Comment: 'sok.  I did a bit more poking under their Terms of Use and apparently they do not let you copy portions of the Wayback Machine.  I assume this is for logistical reasons and not legal ones.