# Linux Programming Essentials

Tags: c++, linux

I was just thrust into Linux programming (Red Hat) after several years of C++ on Win32. So I am not looking for the basics of programming. Rather I am looking to get up to speed with things unique to the Linux programming world, such as packages, etc. In other words, I need to know everything in https://www.redhat.com/courses/rhd251_red_hat_linux_programming/details/ without spending 3K. Any ideas of how I can acquire that knowledge quickly (and relatively cheaply)?

Update: The things that I am used to doing on Windows like building .exe and dlls using VC++,
creating install scripts etc are just done differently on Linux. They use things like yum, make and make install, etc. 
Things like dependency walker that I take for granted in the windows world constantly send me to google while doing linux. Is there a 'set' of new skills somewhere that I can browse or is this more of a learn as you go?

The primary problem is this: As a very experienced programmer in Windows,I am having to ask simple questions like what's the difference between usr\bin and usr\local\bin and I would like to be prepared.

Comment: does Redhat run this course in the UK?  Preferably in London.

Comment: @bruce.banner - The classes seems to be in the US only but you way want to call them and find out for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited because I had to leave a meeting when I originally submitted this, but wanted to complete the information**

Half of that material is learning about development in a Unix-like environment, and for that, I'd recommend a book since it's tougher to filter out useful information from the start.

I'd urge you to go to a bookstore and browse through these books:

- [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949) by Stevens and Rago - this book covers threads, networking, IPC, signals, files, process management
- [Unix Network Programming, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) by Stevens - This book is focused on network programming techniques, design - you might not need this until much later
- [Unix/Linux System Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131480057) - This book covers the more system administrator side of stuff, like directory structure of most Unix and Linux file systems (Linux distributions are more diverse than their Unix-named counterparts in how they might structure their file system)

  Other information accessible online:
- [GCC Online Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) - the comprehensive GNU GCC documentation
- [Beej's network programming guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) - A really well written tutorial to network programming with the use of the BSD API. If you have done work with `winsock`, this should be mostly familiar to you.
- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5's Deployment Guide](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/index.html) - talks specifically about Red Hat EL 5's basic administrative/deployment, like installing with package manager, a Red Hat system's directory structure...
- [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) - Wikipedia article that will have links to the various `make` documentation out there
- [binutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binary_Utilities) - These are the Linux tools used for manipulating object/binaries.
- [GNU Build System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) - Wikipedia article about the traditional build system of GNU software, using autoconf/automake/autogen

Additionally, you will want to learn about [`ldd`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162912), which is like dependency walker in Windows. It lists a target binary's dependencies, if it has any.

And for Debugging, check out [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902922/peters-gdb-tutorial) which talks about a well written GDB tutorial and also links to an IBM guide.

Happy reading.

Comment: I feel like sending you a pack of beer. Thanks for all the cool info.

Answer (score 1):

that is quite a large and diverse topic list. for the programming part i think the C++ library should be portable, things that are not should be documented. for the linux-admin part, i suggest you try to use linux as your main desktop system, as many notions are absorbed via day to day work, there is no magic tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit broad.
What kind of programs are you going to be doing? 
If you stick to standard c++ you're good to go... and just man everything else.

Comment: Not going to -1, but I entirely disagree. `man` pages are okay as a reference, but they're not going to help you actually understand what you're doing.

Comment: But I agree the question is too broad, that standard C++ is identical on either platform, and that we'd have to know more details before we can make more specific suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didnt mean you have to go study the man pages to learn how to code for linux. 
I meant that since we dont know enough of what Jason wants to do, he should stick to standard c++ and when you get stuck you can consult the man pages as a handy reference.

Comment: Most of the time, you have no idea what `man` page to get.  For example, how does one go from "How do I handle multiple sockets and pipes in my code without multithreading" to `man select`?

Answer (score 0):

The single most important thing you'll need is a 99 cent notebook titled "Sys Admin" kept next to your computer.  Keep track of everything you install/update including directory location, date, and method.

Answer (score 0):

For POSIX and such I can recommend [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079)
and having a bookmark to [The single UNIX Specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).

For GCC/GDB and those tools I'm afraid I can't give you any good recommendation.

Hope that helps anyway.

Edit: Duck was slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

A good source is the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.

It's free and covers a lot of you are looking for